# How Can I Get The Next 1st December Date?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a date field in my MySQL table and I want to get all rows before the next 1st Of December. So for example the rows I should get back if I run the query today (Nov 2015) would be any date before 1st Dec 2015. If I run the query after 1st Dec 2015 but before 1st December 2016, it should return all rows with a date of before 1st Dec 2016.

Sorry for lack of code, I have literally no idea where to start with this one!

Comment: your date lesser than concatenate day 1, December month, (actual year if current date less than December from the current year OR current year +1 if the actual date is bigger than 1st dec the actual year)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I create the limit date based on the current month (using [`now()`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_now.asp) to get the current date). If the current month is 12, then the limit is 1-12 of next year (`year(now()+1`), otherwise the current year.

```
select YourDate
from  YourTable
where YourDate < 
    case when month(now())=12 then 
        date(concat(convert(year(now()+1), char), '-12-01')) 
    else 
        date( concat(convert(year(now()), char), '-12-01')) 
    end;
```

Comment: Simple and works. Also rolled my own soluation, which I have posted as another answer. Performance/best standards wise I don't know which is the better but that's another question!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use something like this:

```
SELECT      *
FROM        Table T
WHERE       Some_Date < CASE
                            WHEN MONTH(CURDATE()) < 12 THEN STR_TO_DATE('01, 12, ' + YEAR(CURDATE())),'%d,%m,%Y')
                            ELSE STR_TO_DATE('01, 12, ' + YEAR(CURDATE() + 1)),'%d,%m,%Y')
                        END
```

Disclaimer: I dont have mysql, so I couldn't test it.

Comment: I could not get this code to work for me and I am unsure how to fix due to limited knowledge of MySQL functions.

Comment: My mysql knowledge is limited as well. I would go for @agold's answer, it looks like it does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I did manage my own solution too

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE date < DATE_ADD( MAKEDATE( IF( MONTH( CURRENT_DATE() ) < 12, YEAR( CURRENT_DATE() ), YEAR( CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 1 YEAR ) ), 1), INTERVAL + 11 MONTH )
```